# multiprocessing.Pool: calling helper functions when using apply_async's callback option

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How does the flow of `apply_async` work between calling the iterable (?) function and the callback function?

Setup: I am reading some lines of all the files inside a 2000 file directory, some with millions of lines, some with only a few. Some header/formatting/date data is extracted to charecterize each file. This is done on a 16 CPU machine, so it made sense to multiprocess it.

Currently, the expected result is being sent to a list (`ahlala`) so I can print it out; later, this will be written to *.csv. This is a simplified version of my code, originally based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483512/python-multiprocessing-apply-async-only-uses-one-process) extremely helpful post.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def dirwalker(directory):
  ahlala = []

  # X() reads files and grabs lines, calls helper function to calculate
  # info, and returns stuff to the callback function
  def X(f): 
    fileinfo = Z(arr_of_lines) 
    return fileinfo 

  # Y() reads other types of files and does the same thing
  def Y(f): 
    fileinfo = Z(arr_of_lines)
    return fileinfo

  # results() is the callback function
  def results(r):
    ahlala.extend(r) # or .append, haven't yet decided

  # helper function
  def Z(arr):
    return fileinfo # to X() or Y()!

  for _,_,files in os.walk(directory):
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()
    for f in files:
      if (filetype(f) == filetypeX): 
        pool.apply_async(X, args=(f,), callback=results)
      elif (filetype(f) == filetypeY): 
        pool.apply_async(Y, args=(f,), callback=results)

  pool.close(); pool.join()
  return ahlala
```

Note, the code works if I put all of `Z()`, the helper function, into either `X()`, `Y()`, or `results()`, but is this either repetitive or possibly slower than possible? I know that the callback function is called for every function call, but when is the callback function called?  Is it after `pool.apply_async()`...finishes all the jobs for the processes? Shouldn't it be faster if these helper functions were called within the scope (?) of the first function `pool.apply_async()` takes (in this case, `X()`)? If not, should I just put the helper function in `results()`?

Other related ideas: Are daemon processes why nothing shows up? I am also very confused about how to queue things, and if this is the problem. [This seems like a place to start learning it](http://hairycode.org/2013/07/23/first-steps-with-celery-how-to-not-trip/), but can queuing be safely ignored when using `apply_async`, or only at a noticable time inefficiency?

Comment: Where is `arr_of_lines` coming from? You're passing `f` to `X` and `Y`, but then not using it, and using `arr_of_lines` instead. Can you clarify what's going on there?

Comment: hi, yeah! a lot is going on. For instance, the `f` passed to X(f) is a *.zip file of, say, 5 *.csv files (this characterizse a couple hundred files). So I use `zipfile.ZipFile` to peek at the file contents (the method returns a list of filenames), a `for` loop to use `csv.reader` to read each csv file, and pass out the first two rows/lines (the header, and an example line) -- which is `arr_of_lines`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're asking about a whole bunch of different things here, so I'll try to cover it all as best I can:

The function you pass to `callback` will be executed in the main process (not the worker) as soon as the worker process returns its result. It is executed in a thread that the `Pool` object creates internally. That thread consumes objects from a `result_queue`, which is used to get the results from all the worker processes. After the thread pulls the result off the queue, it executes the `callback`. While your callback is executing, no other results can be pulled from the queue, so its important that the callback finishes quickly. With your example, as soon as one of the calls to `X` or `Y` you make via `apply_async` completes, the   result will be placed into the `result_queue` by the worker process, and then the result-handling thread will pull the result off of the `result_queue`, and your `callback` will be executed.

Second, I suspect the reason you're not seeing anything happen with your example code is because all of your worker function calls are failing. If a worker function fails, `callback` will never be executed. The failure won't be reported at all unless you try to fetch the result from the [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object returned by the call to `apply_async`. However, since you're not saving any of those objects, you'll never know the failures occurred. If I were you, I'd try using `pool.apply` while you're testing so that you see errors as soon as they occur.

The reason the workers are probably failing (at least in the example code you provided) is because `X` and `Y` are defined as function inside another function. `multiprocessing` passes functions and objects to worker processes by pickling them in the main process, and unpickling them in the worker processes. Functions defined inside other functions are not picklable, which means `multiprocessing` won't be able to successfully unpickle them in the worker process. To fix this, define both functions at the top-level of your module, rather than embedded insice the `dirwalker` function.

You should definitely continue to call `Z` from `X` and `Y`, not in `results`. That way, `Z` can be run concurrently across all your worker processes, rather than having to be run one call at a time in your main process. And remember, your `callback` function is supposed to be as quick as possible, so you don't hold up processing results. Executing `Z` in there would slow things down.

Here's some simple example code that's similar to what you're doing, that hopefully gives you an idea of what your code should look like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

# X() reads files and grabs lines, calls helper function to calculate
# info, and returns stuff to the callback function
def X(f): 
    fileinfo = Z(f) 
    return fileinfo 

# Y() reads other types of files and does the same thing
def Y(f): 
    fileinfo = Z(f)
    return fileinfo

# helper function
def Z(arr):
    return arr + "zzz"

def dirwalker(directory):
    ahlala = []

    # results() is the callback function
    def results(r):
        ahlala.append(r) # or .append, haven't yet decided

    for _,_,files in os.walk(directory):
        pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
        for f in files:
            if len(f) > 5: # Just an arbitrary thing to split up the list with
                pool.apply_async(X, args=(f,), callback=results)  # ,error_callback=handle_error # In Python 3, there's an error_callback you can use to handle errors. It's not available in Python 2.7 though :(
            else:
                pool.apply_async(Y, args=(f,), callback=results)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return ahlala


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(dirwalker("/usr/bin"))
```

Output:

```
['ftpzzz', 'findhyphzzz', 'gcc-nm-4.8zzz', 'google-chromezzz' ... # lots more here ]
```

**Edit:**

You can create a dict object that's shared between your parent and child processes using the `multiprocessing.Manager` class:

```
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
helper_dict = m.dict()
for f in files:
    if len(f) > 5:
        pool.apply_async(X, args=(f, helper_dict), callback=results)
    else:
        pool.apply_async(Y, args=(f, helper_dict), callback=results)
```

Then make `X` and `Y` take a second argument called `helper_dict` (or whatever name you want), and you're all set.

The caveat is that this worked by creating a server process that contains a normal dict, and all your other processes talk to that one dict via a Proxy object. So every time you read or write to the dict, you're doing IPC. This makes it a lot slower than a real dict.

Comment: Every question while reading was answered in later paras - beautifully explained! :D The pickling explains why it worked in un-parallelized code! sadly, the reason `X()` and `Y()` are defined inside is for speed. The helper `Z()` made a (faux?)-intelligent dict inside `dirwalker` that would remember if a similar patterned file (regardless of extension/filetype) had been seen before and reduced searches and using `dateutil.parser()`. I'll have to think a way to do both...I was trying to avoid global variables, but it's actually not horrible in this problem. :) if you have time, any suggestions?

Comment: @rebecca I edited my answer to address your dict issue. You can't just use a normal global dictionary, because `Z` is being called across many different processes, which will each get their own copy of the global dict.